# Center prev next buttons vertical responsive

Tags: image, button, slider, gallery

I'm making an image slider, and everything works so far but my previous and next buttons are not centering vertically on the main image. I'm trying to make it responsive as well.

I tried everything but I don't know what I'm missing. The absolute position with top: 50% doesn't seem to do the trick.  Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/GabriellaFarfan/pen/WZRNYm).

```js
$('#imgDetail li img').click(function(){
    $('#unidoor').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
});
$('#next').on('click',function(){
 var imgSrc = $('#unidoor').attr('src');
    var nextSrc = $('ul img[src="'+imgSrc+'"]').closest('li').next().find('img').attr('src');
    console.log(nextSrc);
    nextSrc ==undefined?$('#unidoor').attr('src',$('ul img:first').attr('src')): $('#unidoor').attr('src',nextSrc);
});
$('#prev').on('click',function(){
 var imgSrc = $('#unidoor').attr('src');
    var nextSrc = $('ul img[src="'+imgSrc+'"]').closest('li').prev().find('img').attr('src');
    console.log(nextSrc);
    nextSrc ==undefined?$('#unidoor').attr('src',$('ul img:last').attr('src')): $('#unidoor').attr('src',nextSrc);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  font-size: 100%;
/*   line-height: 1.6; */
/*   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; */
}

.header{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 30px 0 0 0; 
}

.header h1{
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
/*   padding: 0; */
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 0px 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.header li {
  display: block;
  display: inline-block;
/*   border-right: 1px solid #bbb; */
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  height: 25px;
}

.header li:last-child{
  border-right: none;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 40px;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.header li a:hover{
  color: #7bbe9a;
/*   color: #80b198; */
}

#green-room {
  background: #333 !important;
}

#unidoor {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

#prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  transform: translate(-10%, -50%);
}

#next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10%;
  transform: translate(-10%, -50%);
}

/* .previous {left: 10%;}
.next {right: 10%;} */

/* .prev-next-button a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 20%;
} */

#imgDetail ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}

.thumb { 
  width: 25%; 
  height: auto; 
  margin: 15px 5px 0 5px;
}

#imgDetail li { 
  display: inline; margin-right: 10px; 
}

#imgDetail a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
}

#imgDetail a:hover {
  background-color: #7bbe9a;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}

.previous {
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: black;
}

.next {
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: black;
}

/* .round {
  border-radius: 50%;
} */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Daniel Pollack</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
  </head>

  <body id="green-room">
   <div class="header">
      <div id="title"><h1>Lorem Ipsum 3D Online Portfolio</h1></div>
      <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

<div id="imgDetail">
  <br>
    <img src="http://www.davidwightman.net/_images_landscape/Behemot/Behemot_detail_1.jpg" alt="" id="unidoor" />
  <a href="#" id="prev" class="prev-next-button previous">&#8249;</a>
<a href="#" id="next" class="prev-next-button next">&#8250;</a>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="http://www.davidwightman.net/_images_landscape/Behemot/Behemot_detail_1.jpg" class="thumb" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.davidwightman.net/_images_landscape/Behemot/Behemot_detail_2.jpg"  class="thumb" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://www.davidwightman.net/_images_landscape/Behemot/Behemot_detail_3.jpg" class="thumb" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.sr = ScrollReveal({reset: true});
      sr.reveal('#unidoor');
    </script>
    
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello there you can wrap the `<div id="imgDetail">` in an outer div class for instance `<div class="slideshow-container">` and then add your CSS which would look like this:

```
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
```

You can get the changes on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KXaMEj). Happy coding :)